# UTC offset for provided region in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-9

Is there a way to get UTC offset for a given region natively in MarkLogic?

e.g. if region is "America/New_York" then offset should be -5:00 (during Standard Time) or -4:00 (during Daylight Saving Time)

If this can't be achieved with built-in ML functions, what would you recommend?
I want to do it in MarkLogic environment itself.

Answer (score 1):

MarkLogic reads timezone settings from the OS, so change the timezone settings on the hosts themselves.

Here some instructions on how to do it for CentOS/RedHat, which basically comes down to linking /etc/localtime to one of the different predefined timezone files:

https://ma.ttias.be/changing-the-time-and-timezone-settings-on-centos-or-rhel/

HTH!

Comment: this is not what I want. I want to create a XQuery module in ML which will return UTC offset for a given region name. I couldn't find any built-in ML function capable of doing this.

Comment: Ah, looks like I misunderstood the question. parse-dateTime seems cover some of it, but not all. This works: `xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Zn]", "Amsterdam")`, but `xdmp:parse-dateTime("[Zn]", "New_York")` doesn't. It does understand most of the acronyms though, so if you can convert regions to timezone codes, you can get pretty close. Otherwise you might need to hardcode a table in a map:map or such..

Answer (score 1):

The question is unanswerable on its own out of context.  Timezone offsets vary by year as well as region and locality (due to the nature of timezones h-- a political construct, not anything sane).
The rules change over time as the regional organizations that decide such things decide them,  and are not consistent in any rational way.
The rules and tables are built into each OS -- in different ways and completeness/accuracy, depending on the OS, local region and package installations/updates.  Typically they do not go far back in time, and may contain data only for the local region.

The tables are designed to answer primarily "What is the current locale time", and secondary "What is the current TZ offset for a specific zone name".  Getting much more then that is a stretch (such as "When does DST occur" , "Is DST observed in region XYZ", What WAS the localtime or TZ offset for a historic zoned time)

The result, the answer to "What is the UTC Offset for " is not a single numeric constant.

I recommend you determine the intent/use case for the question specifically then create an appropriate table and import it into ML as a document. 
Such as this one:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Adjust according to the actual intended use case, since the question out of context is unlikely to have a single answer that is correct for all purposes.